# Cannot cast array to be of type Any

Tags: swift

I'm working through the online Stanford iOS class - and I'm stuck on a casting problem.

I have a 2D array of Any objects

```
        var totalInfo = [[Any]]()
```

and I'm trying to add arrays of structs to it, like this:

```
        totalInfo.insert(tweet.hashtags, atIndex: 0)
        totalInfo.insert(tweet.urls, atIndex: 1)
        totalInfo.insert(tweet.userMentions, atIndex: 2)
        totalInfo.insert((tweet.media), atIndex: 3)
```

all the attempted insertions are arrays of public structs, but I'm getting an error:

**Cannot convert value of type '[Tweet.IndexedKeyword]' to expected argument type '[Any]'
(Tweet is just the public class containing the struct)

Any ideas why? I thought seeing as the types are all public structs, they should count as "Any" arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to un-nest it a level

```
var totalInfo = [Any]()

totalInfo.insert(tweet.hashtags, atIndex: 0)
totalInfo.insert(tweet.urls, atIndex: 1)
totalInfo.insert(tweet.userMentions, atIndex: 2)
totalInfo.insert((tweet.media), atIndex: 3)
```

Any type is a little complicated and may be confusing the compiler here, but it shouldn't matter because Any can encompass any type, including arrays with different types.

But, for programming style, I wouldn't use this because it's ugly to have to cast things and remember their indexes in a generalized array like this.  I would either use a struct object to store them (it seems tweet is that), or a [String: Any] dictionary, where the String keys were stored in an enum.

Comment: And I think you might want to instead use `.append` rather than `.insert` because it looks like you're trying to insert at the end every time

Comment: Okay - that worked! You're right I guess there's no need to have a 2D array of Any objects, since an array itself is already part of "Any" object - although I'm still not sure why the 2D version didn't work